# Permanently decrypt TrueCrypt SYSTEM drive mounted on a second computer?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, truecrypt

I need to permanently decrypt a TrueCrypt SYSTEM drive that is mounted on a second system.

The *System [menu]* --> *Permanently decrypt system drive/partition* option does not work as the drive's Windows 7 system is blue screening.

I attempted to decrypt the system from the computer it is intended to boot from using the recovery disc. While it said it had decrypted the drive it obviously did not as it keeps asking for a password and in the second system Windows blindly wants to format it. Yes, we have the password as well so no problem there.

I've also tried to use Paragon Partition Manager 2014 to clone the partition however it's apparently not intelligent enough to see a mounted partition.

I can use the Windows 7 repair option to possibly fix the issue but obviously not if it's encrypted.

So how can I permanently decrypt a system drive mounted in a different system using the Windows/program GUI? Note that I had "decrypted" the drive from a recovery disc and a Linux boot disc did not include TrueCrypt. Also I plan to migrate the client to a different encryption since TrueCrypt has been discontinued.

Alternatively suggestions for *free* versions of software (I own a legit copy of Paragon Partition Manager 2014 so if there is a mount option let me know) to reliably clone the partition would be an acceptable answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Decrypting the drive may not remove the TC bootloader.  When you boot the system and get to the password prompt, if you hit escape, it should try to boot windows.  Does that work?  If so, you can just remove the TC bootloader with the software after you fix the bluescreen issue.